# neo4j foreach conditional always executing

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a foreach for an if statement conditional. I only want the condition to run when `$blobFile.extension` is not `null`, however I have tried a few different approaches but this is the only one which executes. However, this query seems to always execute ¯_(ツ)_/¯ maybe I am blind, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

`$blobFile.extension` is either a String or Null.
`image.url` is always set within a Image Node.

```
MERGE (species:Reference:Species{ GUID: $reference.guid })
WITH species
MERGE(image:Image:Media{GUID: $blobFile.imageGuid})
  ON CREATE SET
    image.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(),
    image.creationDate = datetime(),
    image.name = species.name
  ON MATCH SET
    image.name = species.name,
    image.oldFilename = image.filename
WITH species, image

FOREACH(ignoreme in CASE WHEN $blobFile.extension IS NOT NULL THEN [] ELSE [true] END
| SET image.filename = $blobFile.filename, image.url = 'https://www....' + image.GUID + '.' + $blobFile.extension)
```

Comment: Why are using FOREACH here? I don't think you need it? Can you please share what are you trying to do with FOREACH?

Comment: Yes my bad, I only want to set the fields "filename" and "url" within the Image Node when the value passed into the cypher , $blobFile.extension, is set. When $blobFile.extension contains a value(which is not null) I then want the fields to update, otherwise the fields should not update. I hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: Okay, Are you sure that the image already exists with GUID as $blobFile.imageGuid? If not consider separate MERGE statement for Image instead of MERGE on the 3rd line(similar to that on the first line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without FOREACH, as follows:

```
MERGE (species:Reference:Species{ GUID: $reference.guid })
MERGE (image:Image:Media{GUID: $blobFile.imageGuid})
ON CREATE SET
    image.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(),
    image.creationDate = datetime(),
    image.name = species.name
ON MATCH SET
    image.name = species.name
MERGE (species)<-[r6:IS_ABOUT]-(image)
WITH species, image WHERE $blobFile.extension IS NOT NULL
SET 
    image.filename = $blobFile.filename, 
    image.url = 'https://www....' + image.GUID + '.' + $blobFile.extension
```